# Why does altering the height in cssText remove the background: none?

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

I'm altering a class definition in a stylesheet by using the following code:

```
/*
 * At this point it is: 
 * "position: absolute; height: 20px; background-image: none; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"
 * But I actually set "background: none;" in my css file
 */
var cssText = document.styleSheets[ 0 ][ "cssRules" ][ 3 ].style.cssText;

//Just replace the height
document.styleSheets[ 0 ][ "cssRules" ][ 3 ].style.cssText = cssText.replace( "height: 20px", "height: 14px" );

/*
 * Now when I print it out, it's:
 * "position: absolute; height: 20px;"
 */
console.log( document.styleSheets[ 0 ][ "cssRules" ][ 3 ].style.cssText );
```

If I re-append "background: none;" then it puts back in the "background-image: none; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;" stuff. (Oddly, if I append "background-image: none; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;", then it just appears without any background info!)

Any idea why this happens?

**Edit:** The reason I'm using cssText instead of direct access to the styles is that on a number of them I need to set `"!important"` and there's no way other than cssText to do this.

Comment: I think .replace clears all of the css applied to that element. Instead use: `cssRules[0].style.height="14px";`

Comment: @stackErr I know it does, but the string I'm replacing it with *has* those declarations in it! And I can't do what you suggest because I need to kepp "!important" declarations if they're there. There's currently no way to set "!important" through any other way than changing `cssText`.

Comment: Is it possible to redo your styles so they use [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) instead of relying on `!important`?

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir Thanks for the thought but stuff like that is why all this new CSS stuff is awful. Using things like that will make future changes and maintenance a nightmare. Keeping track of the specifity rules for nested elements would make even tiny changes to a document or CSS file unmanageable.

Comment: @DonRhummy - That's not new, actually. That link was to the CSS2 spec. The cascade and specificity are the basis of CSS. IMO `!important` makes code unmanageable since it changes the cascade and specificity rules. I've come across very few situations where `!important` was necessary but changing things around at the end is difficult. Anyways, it was just a thought. Good luck with your issue! :)